# Regex - Matching exactly one single tag

Tags: html, regex

I have a regex to extract the text from an HTML font tag:

```
<FONT FACE=\"Excelsior LT Std Bold\"(.*)>(.*)</FONT>
```

That's working fine until I have some nested font tags. Instead of matching

```
<FONT FACE="Excelsior LT Std Bold">Fett</FONT>
```

the result for string

```
<FONT FACE="Excelsior LT Std Bold">Fett</FONT> + <U>Unterstrichen</U> + <FONT FACE="Excelsior LT Std Italic">Kursiv</FONT> und Normal
```

is

```
<FONT FACE="Excelsior LT Std Bold">Fett</FONT> + <U>Unterstrichen</U> + <FONT FACE="Excelsior LT Std Italic"
```

How do I get only the first tag?

Comment: Could you please post you current RegEx?

Comment: It is disguised as HTML in the first line. @OlafK: Would you enclose the regex in quotes to make it stand out more?

Answer (score 10):

You need to disabale greedy matching with `.*?` instead of `.*`.

```
<FONT FACE=\"Excelsior LT Std Bold\"([^>]*)>(.*?)</FONT>
```

Note that this will fail if there is a attribute like `BadAttribute="<FooBar>"` somewhere after the `FACE` attribute for the `<FONT>` tag. This will mix both matching groups and it could get completly messed up if an attribute would contain `</FONT>`. There is no way araound this because regular expressions cannot count matching tags or quotes. So I absolutly agree with Tomalak - try to avoid using regular expressions for processing XML, HTML, and other markup up languages like these.

Answer (score 4):

You must use the non-greedy star:

```
<FONT FACE=\"Excelsior LT Std Bold\"[^>]*>(.*?)</FONT>
                                    ^^^^^  ^^^
                                      |     |
     match any character except ">" --+     +--------+
                                                     |
   match anything, but only up to the next </FONT> --+
```

The usual warnings about using regex to process HTML apply: You shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use a non-greedy capture denoted by '?'

```
 <FONT FACE=\"Excelsior LT Std Bold\"(.*?)>(.*?)</FONT>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<FONT[^>]*Excelsior LT Std Bold[^>]*></FONT>
```

See Phil Haack's post [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/25/usingregularexpressionstomatchhtml.aspx/).

Here is my C# usage of this expression.  This was used to remove specific CSS and JS files from an HTTP response.

```
const string CSSFormat = "<link[^>]*{0}[^>]*css[^>]*>";
const string JSFormat = "<script[^>]*{0}[^>]*js[^>]*></script>";

static readonly Regex OverrideCss = new Regex(string.Format(CSSFormat, "override-"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
static readonly Regex OverrideIconsJs = new Regex(string.Format(JSFormat, "overrideicons"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```